# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException caused by get Instance

Tags: android, kotlin, initialization, locking

I have the following code for my manager class :

```
11 class MyManager private constructor(application: Application) {
12    companion object {
13        val TAG = MyManager::class.java.simpleName
14
15        private val initialized = AtomicBoolean(false)
16        private lateinit var instance: MyManager
17
18        fun initialize(application: Application) {
19            synchronized(initialized) {
20                if (!initialized.getAndSet(true)) {
21                    instance = MyManager(application)
22                }
23            }
24        }
25
26        val INSTANCE get() = instance
27    }
```

And it's crashing for some of my app users at

```
 val INSTANCE get() = instance
```

line

With the following crash stack

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: 
  at my.package.MyManager$Companion.getINSTANCE (MyManager.kt:26)
  at my.package.MyOtherManager.systemInitialization (MyOtherManager.kt:585)
  at my.package.MyOtherManager.doRun (MyOtherManager.kt:433)
  at my.package.MyOtherManager.access$doRun (MyOtherManager.kt:56)
  at my.package.MyOtherManager$launchThread$launched$1$1.invoke (MyOtherManager.kt:126)
  at my.package.MyOtherManager$launchThread$launched$1$1.invoke (MyOtherManager.kt:56)
  at my.package.MyOtherManagerKt$sam$i$java_lang_Runnable$0.run (Unknown Source:2)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:919)
```

What I understand from similar errors is that I am getting the instance before setting it, but I don't see how is that possible if my `initialized` boolean is false by default and I am setting the `instance` variable when it's the case.

Is there something wrong with the way I instantiate the Class?
What's the behaviour for my line 19, when I call `synchronized`, does it wait to execute it first before going to line 26 (getting the instance) or there is a risk to get the instance before the code inside `synchronized` block being called?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're calling `initialize` before _every_ read of `INSTANCE`?

Comment: You are right, I have probably an INSTANCE call before initialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has a few problems.

> What's the behaviour for my line 19, when I call `synchronized`, does it wait to execute it first before going to line 26 (getting the instance)

These lines of code have no enforced relationship.  There's nothing to enforce that `initialize(...)` is called before any reads of the `INSTANCE` property.  You'd need to make sure you call `initialize` before *every* access to `INSTANCE` (or `instance`, for that matter).

Another problem is that your use of synchronization here is kind of odd.  You have a `synchronized` block, as though you expect `initiaize` to be called from multiple threads, but it's just initialized with an `Application`.  This isn't necessary, just call it once at app startup.

Another problem is that, depending on exactly how you're setting this up, you might have a thread-safety issue.  If you're reading this from another thread, and the initialization of `instance` doesn't [happens-before](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/happens-before.html) the start of that other thread, the initialization might not be visible to that other thread.  You could fix this by making `instance` `volatile`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Concerning `volatile` usage, if I do it, I need to add it to both `initialized` and ìnstance` variables?